# can't get theme b or c working in phone gap app

Tags: jquery, cordova

This is a real simple index.html I am using inside an Xcode phone gap projection.... I seem to only be able to get the black app bar framework working.. and not themes b an dc etc.... was trying to use other themes to compare differences.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile: Theme Download</title>
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/retire-ipad.min.css" / -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script t type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script t type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- from template -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b"  data-content-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back"  data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Back</a>
           <h1>Page Title</h1>
            <a href="../../" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Page content goes here.</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->



</body>
```

Is it the versions of query or is it something else?

-T